# gnu parallel + sed to edit both csv header and contents

Tags: bash, csv, sed, gnu-parallel, gnu-findutils

I'm trying to use command line tools to edit some CSV I have in the following format for several year folders:

- dataset

  - year_1 (i.e. 1929)

    - csv_filename_1.csv
    - csv_filename_2.csv
    - csv_filename_3.csv
    - ...
  - year_2

    - ...

I'm trying to append the file name to its content, creating a new column called `filename` with `./year_1/csv_filename_1.csv` to all columns in it. After that, I would gzip it.

Due to the number of year folders (almost 100) and the CSVs quantities in each (totaling 100k+), I plan to use gnu parallel to run it, and

I was trying to use sed doing something like

```
fname="1929/csv_filename_1.csv" &&          \ # to simulate parallel's parameterization
    sed -E -e '1s/$/,filename/'             \ # append ",filename" to CSV header
           -e '2,\$s/$/,${fname}/' ${fname} \ # append the filename string to the content
```

But I can't get the sed to work with the second expression because I either get "${fname}" written as-is to the file, or the sed error `"sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: '\'"` complaining about a comma or the slash. I also have tried to group the expressions like `-e '1{s/$/,filename/};2,\${s/$/,${fname}/}'` for no avail.

Currently, I gave up sed and started trying with awk, but not knowing why it didn't work is bothering me, so I came to ask why and how to make it work.

Just one more piece of info regarding how I intend to run this thing. It would be something like

```
find ~/dataset -iname "*csv" -print0 | parallel -0 -j0 '<the whole command here (sed + gz)>'
```

How could I do this? What am I forgetting? Thanks, folks!

PS: I just got it with awk

```
awk -v d="csv_filename_1.csv" -F"," 'FNR==1{a="filename"} FNR>1{a=d} {print $0","a}' csv_filename_1.csv | less
```

Comment: "Something like?"  Two comments: 1) "expression 1" char 6 would indict the first `-e` command.   2) However it's expression 2 that seemingly would generate a complaint about char 6.  ie  `sed -n '2,\$ p'`  gets:  sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated address regex`.  (Because there is no reason to escape the $ there) Net: if you want the sed explained, you need to show exactly what causes the error.

Comment: Yep, there might be some copy-paste issues, since I got it from some intermediate try. I was really frustrated at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and sed):

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' | parallel sed -i \''1s/$/,filename/;1!s#$#,{}#'\' {}
```

Use find to deliver the filename to the parallel command.

Use sed to append `,filename` to the heading of each file and the file name present in `{}` to each line in the file.

N.B. The use of alternative delimiters `s#...#...#` in the second sed command to allow for the filename slashes. Also the find should be executed in the `dataset` directory.

Comment: Wow! I was aware of the "!" operator but didn't think of using it that way. And regarding the alternative delimiter, that is just wow. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @paulochf enter `[sed]` in search box of stackoverflow and choose `learn more`